# Chaining 3 jQuery selectors for an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following where I bind the same event to 3 elements. Is there a way to have the selectors do this in 1 line , like a "OR" in the selector?

```
$('.fundLoad').keyup(queryRequest);
$('.fundName').keyup(queryRequest);
$('.companyName').keyup(queryRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a comma:

```
$('.fundLoad, .fundName, .companyName').keyup(queryRequest);
```

jQuery uses standard CSS selectors as a basis for it's selector specification.

Comment: Ah, the simplest solutions....